# The character group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters

Prove that the one-dimensional characters of a group $G$ form a group under multiplication of functions. This group is called the character of $G$. Here's my try.

Let $g$ be an element of order $k$ present in some conjugacy class. Let $X(g)$ denote the character of an element in the same conjugacy class as $g$. Since all the characters we're concerned with are one-dimensional, all their values on one conjugacy class are powers of the k-th root of unity. Now a group has to be closed under multiplication and taking inverses: $$X_1\left(g\right)X_2\left(g\right)=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{k}t_1}e^{\frac{2\pi i}{k}t_2}=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{k}\left(t_1+t_2\right)}$$ and so in order for the group to be closed under multiplication the element $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{k}\left(t_1+t_2\right)}$ has to be the value some character $X_3$ takes on the conjugacy class represented by the element $g$. Similarly taking inverses translates to the existence of a character which attains the value $e^{\frac{-2\pi i}{k}t}$ on the same conjugacy class.

But how can I be sure that for each $t_1$ and $t_2$ (powers of the k-th root of unity) there exists a one dimensional character which attains the values of the powers $t_1+t_2$ (for closure under multiplication) and another that attains the value $-t$ (for closure under taking inverses).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$u: G \to \Bbb{C}^*$ is an homomorphism iff $u(gh) = u(g)u(h)$. Let $w(g) = u(g)v(g)$ then $w(gh) = u(gh)v(gh)= u(g)u(h)v(g)v(h) = w(g)w(h)$.

Same for $z(g) =1/u(g)$.

If $G$ is a finite group then $u(g)$ is a $|G|$-th root of unity.

The character table is something different : it is the traces of the finite dimensional (irreducible) representations, and they don't form a group (nor do the representations). Since $tr(AB)= tr(BA)$ we obtain $tr(\rho(ghg^{-1})) =tr(\rho(g^{-1})\rho(gh))= tr(\rho(h))$.

For the homomorphisms we have much more : since $\Bbb{C}^*$ is abelian we obtain $u(ghl) = u(hgl)$ thus $u(g) = u(h)$ whenever $g h^{-1} \in [G,G]$ (the commutator subgroup).

$G^{ab} = G/[G,G]$ is abelian and the characters of $G$ is the same as the characters of $G^{ab}$. If $G$ is finite or finitely generated then so is $G^{ab}$ and it is easy to find all its characters.

Comment: I don't understand what all this has to do with the original problem which asks to prove that the one-dimensional characters form a group?

Comment: please see the edit as I can't wrap my mind around your answer.

Comment: @Km356 Again forget about conjugacy classes. If $u,v$ are two characters then $w = u \times v$ and $z = u^{-1}$ are characters, thus the characters form a group.

Comment: But how is this not relevant ? the product of two characters gives a complex valued function which is only called a character when it has a specific connection with the elements of the group $G$, ie.. the right values for every conjugacy class that make it distinct from other characters of the group. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Character = homomorphism  $G \to\Bbb{C}^*$, the pointwise product of two homomorphisms $G \to\Bbb{C}^*$ is an homomorphism $G \to\Bbb{C}^*$, same for  the inverse.

Comment: @Km356 1-dimensional characters of $G$ are homomorphisms $G\to\Bbb{C}^*$. That is all you need. If you include the characters of all the representatios then the result does not hold.